# Extremely slow wake up from suspend?

Tags: lubuntu, suspend

I have a problem with my Lubuntu laptop. When I suspend the laptop it takes about 5 minutes to wake up again. Cold boot takes around 1. What could be the problem? I'm fairly new to Linux, so please tell me what code should I post, etc.
On Windows it woke up in seconds.

free -h

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
Mem:          1970Mi       711Mi        68Mi        61Mi       191Mi        63Mi 
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

sysctl vm.swappiness vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema
free -h
`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          1970Mi       711Mi        68Mi        61Mi       191Mi        63Mi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B`

sysctl vm.swappiness

`vm.swappiness = 60`

Not sure how to format this better.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, it belongs as an edit to your question. I've added it there for you. You have very little RAM, and no SWAP. What version Ubuntu? Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: I agree with @heynnema, you're likely using LXQt given the missing swap but it's much better if we're given details about your desktop (without release details we can't know what you're using; Lubuntu only narrows it down to LXQt or LXDE). I'd enable swap firstly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Lubuntu 20.04 is running slow when I use Opera or LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274118/why-lubuntu-20-04-is-running-slow-when-i-use-opera-or-libreoffice)

Comment: Yes, that's also my accepted answer.

Comment: Is swap relevant in relation to *suspend*? (As opposed to hibernate?)