# Cannot install A GUI in my computer

Tags: 20.04, gnome, software-installation, gdm

I am on Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I try to boot up my computer I get nothing only black screen. If I press <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then I can see only `/dev/sda2 clean`, etc. Nothing else. It looks like there is no GUI on it.

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>f5</kbd> to enter a tty and logged in. Now when I try to install a GUI I get dependencies error. But when I install something else it was doing fine, e.g.,
Aptitude: `sudo apt install aptitude` was just installed without any error.

The exact error message while installing gnome was:

```
 depend on gnome-setting-daemon (>= 3.24) but it's not going to be installed. 
  depend on gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92) but it's not going to be installed.
```

I don't know why I cannot I install gnome.

Comment: If you want to install gnome with gdm3 then you can install tasksel `sudo apt install tasksel` and `sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  From the versions mentioned it looks like *bionic* or 18.04; but it's best if we're told & not guessing.  I'd `sudo apt update` & read the output there looking for clues (warnings, errors, missing lines etc) as the package is available `gnome-shell | 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.7             | bionic-updates          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x` but again as we don't know your release; only you can interpret issues correctly.

Comment: @Algnis : tasksel installed properly but when I tried to install ubuntu-desktop with that command, got error message "tasksel: apt-get failed (100)"
Any advise? thanks.

Comment: @guiverc : I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Release 20.04, Codename focal. Tried sudo apt update and there no warning at all (reading, building, state informatin done). I just buy this pc for a week and before no problem at all to login to ubuntu.

I tried to download gnome-shell with sudo apt install gnome-shell:
depends: evolution-data-server (>=3.33.1) but it's not going to be installed.
gnome-settings-daemon (>=3.16.0)
libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>=13)

recommends: gdm3 (>= 3.10.0.1-3)
gnome-control-center (>=1:3.25.2)
ubuntu session and gnome-session not going to be installed

Comment: Please amend your question and add additional details there; comments can be deleted. Your question mentions no specific release; only package rules.. Your use of tags are also unclear; as Ubuntu Server doesn't use `gdm3` or GNOME - they're desktop packages.

Comment: @Ferry I can not give a proper advice but if you don't want your machine to be useless you can install some other desktop environnt other then gnome , For eg install LXQT , I also suffered the same problem and know how it feels to have LXQT on a 2GB ubuntu installation , bit still it is better than having no gui at all

Comment: oh sorry, I'm still new and try to learn linux so that's why my explanation not really good.
so the problem is I can't go to the GUI when I start my pc server and it's stuck in the black screen with the ""/dev/sda2: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks and can't login" message error.

@Algnis how to install LXQT, could you help to teach me how to download it and use it? thanks

Comment: @Ferry Well you can install it by , `sudo tasksel install lubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt install LXQT*`

Comment: @Ferry don't use  pc server , as it is a desktop installation you could not say it as server , Server is something else then this

Comment: Or let me tell you a cool thing `sudo tasksel` try this out

Comment: @Algnis approve your edit, thanks. tried to download lubuntu-desktop but failed also "tasksel: apt-get failed (100)"

while LXQT* also failed with notification:
Depends: pavucontrol-qt
pavucontrol but it's not going to be installed

Recommends: quassel, quassel-client, hexchat, irssi, weechat but it's not going to be installed

lxqt-build-tools: depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.5.0) 
qttools5-dev but it's not going to be installed..

this problem makes me stress :(

Comment: All users of this site can edit their own questions; @Algnis if you're using Lubuntu with 2GB of RAM, ensure you have swap enabled (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-create-a-swapfile-in-lubuntu-20-04-20-10/1959 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274118/why-lubuntu-20-04-is-running-slow-when-i-use-opera-or-libreoffice)   Lubuntu is a 'universe' or community package; it requires 'universe' enabled; some install media doesn't enable it by default  https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: Does your hardware meet the minimum specs for GNOME?  esp. graphic requirements (eg. `3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB`); many servers do **not** meet those requirements - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  but can run *lighter* desktops successfully.  4GiB is the minimum recommended RAM for GNOME

Comment: Ferry , if you can't do this then Reinstalling ubuntu is the only choice left . :/ o_O

Comment: I used Xeon-R E2224G, RAM 16GB, Mesa Intel UHD Graphics P630, SSD 512GB. I think the spec is quite enough right? @Algnis is it possible to reinstalling with flashdisk but maintain the program and the data? because it'll take a time to install the apps again. thanks before guys

Comment: Well it is a good specs , and you can install whithout losing your home directory , but apps may not be saved